# python3 making list of dict using lamba

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, inline

```
def querySet_to_list(qs):
    l = list()
    for i in qs:
        d = dict()
        for k,v in i.items():
            d[k] = v
        l.append(d)
    return l
```

I want to convert this function to inline syntax.

e.g

```
list(map(lambda x:x.items(), [q for q in qs]))  # this not working...
```

This work is difficult for me.

I use this code in django view

```
def get_software(request):
    ss = Software.objects.values()
    return JsonResponse(querySet_to_list(ss), safe=False)
```

Comment: what does this function do? can you provide an input-output example? It looks like you are taking a list of dicts and converting it to a, well, list of dicts..

Comment: but how is the outgoing `l` any different than the incoming `qs`? Can you provide any dummy data?

Comment: I edited content "I use this code in django view".

Comment: `return copy.deepcopy(qs)`?

Comment: sorry, deepcopy is not what I want.. I want to serialize django queryset to list.

Comment: `# this not working...` is not helpful. Provide the exact error and stacktrace or input/output data. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
def querySet_to_list(qs):
    return [dict(q) for q in qs]

def get_software(request):
    ss = Software.objects.values()
    return JsonResponse(querySet_to_list(ss), safe=False)
```

I solve this issue. thank you.
"django queryset.values() to python list"